# Mask or custom Path Name in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there a way to mask or change the path name that the browser shows in the URL?

I mean, in my browser the url shows the filename of my JS **ACG001** and it would be better if i show something like Catalogs or some custom name instead of the path name

```
http://localhost:XXX/#/ACG001
```

I already know that i could change the path to my custom name but my current menu have ACG001 as path and i can not change it

```
<Route path="/ACG001" component={ACG001} />
```